# Bag of words tokenizes every letter and not word

Tags: python, string, list

I have a bag of words implementation here I found on the web. I'm reading in a text file of many sentences that I will run through generate_bagOfWords

```
def stopword_clean(sentence):
    ignore = ["i", "me", "my", "myself", "we", "our", "ours", "ourselves", "you", "your", "yours", "yourself",
              "yourselves", "he", "him", "his", "himself", "she", "her", "hers", "herself", "it", "its", "itself",
              "they", "them", "their", "theirs", "themselves", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "these",
              "those", "am", "is", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", "have", "has", "had", "having", "do",
              "does", "did", "doing", "a", "an", "the", "and", "but", "if", "or", "because", "as", "until", "while",
              "of", "at", "by", "for", "with", "about", "against", "between", "into", "through", "during", "before",
              "after", "above", "below", "to", "from", "up", "down", "in", "out", "on", "off", "over", "under", "again",
              "further", "then", "once", "here", "there", "when", "where", "why", "how", "all", "any", "both", "each",
              "few", "more", "most", "other", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "not", "only", "own", "same", "so", "than",
              "too", "very", "s", "t", "can", "will", "just", "don", "should", "now", "This", "It", "I"]

    words = re.sub("[^\w]", " ", sentence).split()
    clean_text = [w for w in words if w.lower() not in ignore]
    return clean_text


def tokenize(sentences):
    words = []
    for sentence in sentences:
        x = stopword_clean(sentence)
        words.extend(x)

    words = sorted(list(set(words)))
    return words


def generate_bagOfWords(finalsentences):
    vocab = tokenize(finalsentences)
    print("Word list for document \n{0} \n", format(vocab));

    for sentence in finalsentences:
        words = stopword_clean(sentence)
        bag_vector = numpy.zeros(len(vocab))
        for w in words:
            for i, word in enumerate(vocab):
                if word == w:
                    bag_vector[i] += 1

        print("{0} \n{1}\n".format(sentence, numpy.array(bag_vector)))
```

The problem is I read in a lot of sentences like this:

```
trainingFile = open(r"D:\Desktop\\1565964985_2925534_train_file.data", "r")

# arrays for the sentiments and reviews
sentiment = []
review = []

# for loop that reads each line
for line in trainingFile:
    # data field array separated by tab
    dataFields = line.split("\t")

    # sentiment holds the positive or negative sentiment of the review
    sentiment.append(dataFields[0])
    # review holds the text from the review
    review.append(dataFields[1])
```

Which makes my indexes like this:

```
Review[0]: This book is such a life saver.  It has been so helpful to be able to go back to track trends, answer pediatrician questions, or communicate with each other when you are up at different times of the night with a newborn.  I think it is one of those things that everyone should be required to have before they leave the hospital.  We went through all the pages of the newborn version, then moved to the infant version, and will finish up the second infant book (third total) right as our baby turns 1.  See other things that are must haves for baby at [...]
```

I get an output of this

```
['1', 'W', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'y']
T 
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

h 
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

i 
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

s 
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

But for the whole sentence.

However if I do this

```
    review[0] = ["This book is such a life saver.  It has been so helpful to be able to go back to track trends, answer pediatrician questions, or communicate with each other when you are up at different times of the night with a newborn.  I think it is one of those things that everyone should be required to have before they leave the hospital.  We went through all the pages of the newborn version, then moved to the infant version, and will finish up the second infant book (third total) right as our baby turns 1.  See other things that are must haves for baby at [...]"]
```

It works correctly

```
['1', 'See', 'able', 'answer', 'baby', 'back', 'book', 'communicate', 'different', 'everyone', 'finish', 'go', 'haves', 'helpful', 'hospital', 'infant', 'leave', 'life', 'moved', 'must', 'newborn', 'night', 'one', 'pages', 'pediatrician', 'questions', 'required', 'right', 'saver', 'second', 'things', 'think', 'third', 'times', 'total', 'track', 'trends', 'turns', 'version', 'went']
This book is such a life saver.  It has been so helpful to be able to go back to track trends, answer pediatrician questions, or communicate with each other when you are up at different times of the night with a newborn.  I think it is one of those things that everyone should be required to have before they leave the hospital.  We went through all the pages of the newborn version, then moved to the infant version, and will finish up the second infant book (third total) right as our baby turns 1.  See other things that are must haves for baby at [...] 
[1. 1. 1. 1. 2. 1. 2. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 2. 1. 1. 1. 1. 2. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 2. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 2. 1.]
```

What's going on here and how can I convert my entire array to a string that works correctly?

Comment: Did you miss a `.split()` somewhere?

Comment: Where would this split go? When I'm reading in the text?

Comment: When you want to convert a string, which is an iterable of characters, to an iterable over words.

Comment: I added a .split() to 
    review.append(dataFields[1]) -> review.append(dataFields[1].split()) which gets me closer but still no cigar. This 
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.] book 
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]    I need the whole sentence as one list element like at the end of my original post.

Comment: Well? Did it work?

Comment: Not exactly. Now it runs bagOfWords for every word and not the sentence as a whole.